# rsync delete option not working

Tags: unix, rsync

rsync is not deleting files from destination directory, though Adding/modifying files working properly .

When I am using below command, i am getting below error :

```
[MS-PROD-FTP]$rsync -rave --del "ssh -i $cert" $Local_Dir/* 

$USER@$Remote_Hostname:$Remote_Dir**

rsync: Failed to exec --del: No such file or directory (2)

rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.6]

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]

rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Below command one executed with no error ,But files are not getting deleted in dest directory .

```
[MS-PROD-FTP]$rsync --del -rave  "ssh -i $cert" $Local_Dir/* 

$USER@$Remote_Hostname:$Remote_Dir**

sending incremental file list

sent 136 bytes  received 12 bytes  296.00 bytes/sec
total size is 66  speedup is 0.45
```

Can someone help here ?

Comment: `--delete` is the option...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: the rsync 3.1.1 that I have here on debian uses --del as an alias for --delete-during. But it does indeed look like Piyush is using some other rsync, that doesn't accept --del yet?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès joosteto . I am using rsync 3.0.6 provided in amazon ec2 instance and tried both --del and --delete but its not deleting at remote location . See below the command i tried . 

rsync -rav --delete -e  "ssh -i $cert" $Local_Dir/* $USER@$Remote_Hostname:$Remote_Dir
sending incremental file list

sent 119 bytes  received 12 bytes  262.00 bytes/sec
total size is 79  speedup is 0.60

Comment: Posting correct ans below :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was /* , correct command is :

rsync -rave --del "ssh -i $cert" $Local_Dir/ $USER@$Remote_Hostname:$Remote_Dir/

Thanks ,